# Pages load issue on local IIS serv

Tags: iis, ssl, coldfusion

I'm currently developing a web application running locally on IIS 10 with coldfusion 9.

I have a problem right now, caused by SSL I think. Since it's a backoffice, it has to be https, so I used our company certificate to install it locally on my computer and I linked it to the website I'm developing. The problem is whenever I use the https connection, all the pages are loaded twice (it isn't visible, but for instance when I submit a form, the data are inserted twice in the database).
I manage, with luck, to solve this issue by changing the SSL parameters "client certificates" from ignore to accept but when I do that, from time to time (like 1 out of 3) the page that I want to load takes forever (like 30s) and as I can see, uses 100% of the CPU.

It doesn't come from my code (I think) because when I navigate with http, I have none of the problem listed above.

Does anyone have an idea with this is happening and how to solve it ?

Thanks in advance ! If you need any further information, ask and I'll try to give it to you !

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think the pages are being loaded twice?

Comment: This could be a compatibility issue. I'm surprised you got CF9 installed on IIS10 as they only just released support for CF10/11 in the last few days. Before the patch, getting CF11 running was a pain. CF9 is not intended to work on IIS10 at all.

Comment: I noticed that when I submited my forms, the data were instered twice. So I made a test with a session variables that the page just increase by one and at each load of that page the variable value was increased by 2 and not by 1 as expected :/

Comment: I actually didn't got it installed, I upgraded my win7 to win10 but CF9 was already installed ;) That could be a compatibility issue but I hope not, I'll try on a win7 machine !

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try on a win7 machine but I've tried on CF11 and the issue is not happening any more :) (Thanks for your help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now installed Coldfusion 11 and with that the issue is not happening anymore. So I'm pretty sure it's a compatibility answer.